# Simpler alternative to np.where() to change row value pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` like this one:

```
            id    year      x1     x2  ...        x15        
0         1000  1973.0   3.277  0.297  ...        NaN        
1         1000  1974.0   3.494  0.010  ...        NaN        
2         1000  1975.0   5.335  0.180  ...  27.686086  
3         1000  1976.0   7.143  0.348  ...  25.982902  
4         1000  1977.0   3.503  0.234  ...  16.120394  
       ...     ...     ...    ...  ...        ...        
140008  184740  1983.0  12.728  0.000  ...  37.367403  
140009  184740  1984.0   9.219  0.000  ...  29.819767  
140010  187839  1986.0  -0.016  0.000  ...        NaN      
140011  187839  1987.0  -0.416  0.000  ...        NaN       
140012  187839  1988.0  -0.925  0.000  ...  -0.578135
```

For an empirical works, I need to perform some row-by-row computations, say they are contained in the function `foo(row)`, whose value needs to be put in the column `x15` and which returns `V`. `foo(row)` uses the values of some columns of `row` plus the value of `x15` of the previous row. The procedure I have to perform is iterative, i.e. it starts by giving a value of zero to `x15` (to initialize it in the first period), applies `foo(row)` on the first row, set the value of the corresponding `x15` equal to the output and then repeates the process for the following row. This has to be done sequentially (over `year`) for each identifier (`id`). To give an example:

```
def foo(row):
    row['x15']=(calculations involving the columns of that row)+(other calculations of the previous value of x15)
```

The solution I have thought about is to apply `foo(row)` in the first row (for each `id`) and assign its value to `x15`; creating a new columns of zeros, ````x16``` and use

```
row['x16']=np.where((df['id']==row['id'])&(df['year']>=row['year']),V, row['x16'])
```

The last line is written in that way so that I can specify `foo(row)` like this

```
def foo(row):
    row['x15']=(calculations involving the columns of that row)+(other calculations using x16)
```

By copying the output of `foo(row)` into `x16` for all the years equal to the one I am applying the function, for the same firm, I can keep the function `foo(row)` only on the rows and thus I can then
`df.apply(foo, axis=1)` and I get what I want.

The problem with this approach is that I have quite many `np.where()` computations like the one just mentioned and I saw that this is creating bottlenecks in my overall function, due to the index-search I use in it `(df['id']==row['id'])&(df['year']>=row['year'])`. Do you have some suggestions on how to perform the same thing as explained above with another approach, such that I can skip the `np.where()` part and speed up the whole thing?

Comment: I didn't read the whole question but you can use `df.query('<column> == <value>')`

Comment: A `where` is fine when used once for the whole array, but you are using it repeatedly for each row.  Doing anything row by row is slow in `pandas`.  And within the `where` you are doing `df['id']==row['id']` (and for 'year') testing the row value against the whole column.  I don't see the purpose of that test in the (wordy) description.

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed. Even with wordy descriptions there are people who just can't get it